# ACRA backend for windows using .net

Tags: android, .net, web-services, acra

**ACRA backend for windows using .net**

how can we use our own server (.net) as ACRA backend

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Or you want somebody to create the server instead of you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the documentation:
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-to-your-own-self-hosted-script